# multiple dependent variable using tilde (~)

Tags: r, tilde

How to  sum multiple column using aggregate function (formula method) ?
I am trying to work following code;

```
aggregate(cty,hwy ~ class+ Manufacturer, data = mpg, mean)
```

it should give me sum of hwy, sum of cty by manufacturer and class

Comment: This should get you there using dplyr, not agg:

`df<-mpg %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(class+ Manufacturer) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total=sum(cty), total2 = sum(hwy))`

Comment: ahh... that was simple, i tried c(cty,hwy) but that didn't work so i thought i might have been something else . Thank you so much